# Error: "The import helpers cannot be resolved"

Tags: java, import

I am trying to run a Dynamic Web Project in Eclipse Helios. A colleague and I both downloaded the same classes from the same server and imported them via copy and paste on Eclipse. I am trying to run the project on Apache Tomcat 7 and have it configured correctly as far as I can see. 
However many of my classes are given the following error:

> The import helpers cannot be resolved

on the following line:

```
<%@ page import="helpers.*" %>
```

Does anybody with a more in depth knowledge of the issue know of the problem and how to fix it?

Thanks,
Stephen.

Comment: It means that Eclipse can't find the package named "helpers". Do you have such a package in your sources, or in any of the jars used by the webapp?

Comment: @JBNizet 

Within the project there is a WEB-INF folder...within there is a classes folder...and within there is a helpers folder containing numerous classes, would this be the one? 

After your comment I tried changing:
<%@ page import="helpers.*" %>
to:
<%@ page import="WEB-INF/classes/helpers.*" %>

It didn't work, is that what you would suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Eclipse's Package Explorer (on the left), under your project there should be an entry called `Web App Libraries`, expand it and see if there is `<some_project_path>/WEB-INF/classes` listed? This would tell you if your webapp project is configured to use your generated classes on the app classpath.

If it's not the case, you may go to your project properties, select "Java Build Path", and on the "Source" tab set your `Default output folder` to be `<yourapp>/WebContent/WEB-INF/classes` - or whatever, depending on your webapp's structure.